# dynamically select a field to update in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class in Java 8 like:

```
class state
{
   LocalDateTime date1;
   LocalDateTime date2;
   LocalDateTime date3;
   LocalDateTime date4;
   LocalDateTime date5; 
}
```

Based on certain condition, i will have to select one of the date field to update it with utc time. I have to create a instance of this class by updating 1 field at a time rest of the fields will be empty.

I can do like below but I am wondering if there is any elegant way to achieve this. here status is an enum.

```
   switch case(status)
   case "1"
     new state(UTC.now, null,null, null, null);
   case "2"
     new state(null, UTC.now, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Consider using a Map<Condition, LocalDateTime> to find/replace the relevant instance. If multiple conditions point to the same instance, then a multi-key map could be used.

Answer (score 2):

Once you made the decision to make separate fields, you lost the ability to do this elegantly.

```
class State {
    List<LocalDateTime> dates = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

now it can be as simple as: `state.getDates().set(Integer.parseInt(status), ...);`

If 'status' isn't a number, perhaps:

```
class State {
    Map<String, LocalDateTime> dates = new HashMap<>();
}
```

and then: `states.put(status, ...);`

There are plenty more ideas in this vein.

Answer (score 0):

An idea without changing your date fields into a collection...

Put the switch in a State constructor:

```
public State(Status stat) {
    switch case(stat)
    case one:
        date1 = UTC.now;
        break;
    case two:
        date2 = UTC.now;
        break;
    ...
}
```

I'm assuming `Status` looks something like this:

```
enum Status {
    one(1), two(2);

    private int stat;
    private Status(int stat) {
        this.stat = stat;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.stat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first idea is great, but using reflection here is just asking for trouble. I would suggest editing the answer to get rid of that; you lose type safety, you're 'stringly typing' your variables, 'find references' scripts in IDEs fail to work, and in general it just smells.

Comment: "you're 'stringly typing' your variables, 'find references' scripts in IDEs" -- you could say the same thing about your solutions using collections. You would only know which date (1, 2, 3, etc) is being set at runtime. Ideally he wouldn't have 5 separate date objects, and I would use one of your solutions.

Comment: No, you can't say the same thing about the collections. After all, the only field around to ask the question 'where are you accessed' of - is the collection, and the IDE will give the proper answers. Vs. the reflection situation where you do have a field, but asking the question will give an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is Builder Design Pattern useful?

```
class stateBuilder {

    LocalDateTime date1;
    LocalDateTime date2;
    LocalDateTime date3;
    LocalDateTime date4;
    LocalDateTime date5;

    public stateBuilder setDate1(int date) {
                this.date1= date;
        return this;
    }

    public stateBuilder setDate2(int date) {
                this.date2= date;
        return this;
    }
    // So on for other instance members

    public state build() {
        return  new State(date1,date2,date3,date4,date5);
    }
}
```

And you can call:

```
State s = new stateBuilder().setDate1(UTC.now).build();
```